# how to pass more than one value in sub query

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 
  @startdate nvarchar(100),
  @enddate nvarchar(100)
as
begin
   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

   select @cols = 
       STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype) from VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')   

   set @query =
     'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + '
     from  ( select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
     from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid where dtime   between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + 
  '''and locid IN  ' + (select CAST(l.Locid  as varchar(max))  from Location_tbl l)
 + '  ) d pivot ( count(Vtype)     for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '

   execute(@query)
end
```

While executing this am getting error like this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How i can pass more than 1 value in my sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnew] 

    @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
    @enddate NVARCHAR(100)

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE
          @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
        FROM dbo.VType_tbl
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query =
    'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + '
     from  ( 
            select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
            from Transaction_tbl t 
            join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
            where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + ''' 
                and locid IN (SELECT l.Locid FROM dbo.Location_tbl l)
    ) d pivot ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query

END
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your problem lays here:

```
(select CAST(l.Locid  as varchar(max))  from Location_tbl l)
```

You're trying to form a string from an unknown amount of rows returned from that.

You could just make that part of the string.